# Yii2: update field with query builder

Tags: updating, query-builder, yii2

How can I update field with query builder in Yii2? I can't find this in documentation.

Thanks!

**UPD**

This is the solution:

```
// UPDATE
$connection = Yii::$app->db;
$connection->createCommand()->update('user', ['status' => 1], 'age > 30')->execute();
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? show us some code.

Comment: @tareq - problem is that I have nothing to show because I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Query builder is for select queries only (sum, max, count too). You should use other methods - AR or raw queries (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-dao.md#basic-sql-queries)

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I feel like it may be useful to point out that today (in  2021) the query builder can be used for any query. Like other answers have pointed out, you can call update() on the builder object. `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('tableName', ['field' => 'value'], condition)->execute()`. The 2nd parameter is a key-value pair of the fields you want to set and the values you want to set them to. The 3rd parameter is the condition for the update and could be a simple string or an array following Yii's "where array syntax".

Answer (score 24):

Create command can be used directly as follows :

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE table SET column1=:column1, column2=:column2 WHERE id=:id")
->bindValue(':id', your_id)
->bindValue(':column1', :column1_value)
->bindValue(':column2', :column2_value)
->execute();
```

Comment: How can I do `WHERE id=:id OR id=:id2 OR id=:id3` ..etc in a loop? Do I just construct the query string in that loop or is there a better way?

Comment: "UPDATE table SET column1=:column1, column2=:column2 WHERE id=:id1 OR id=:id2 OR id=:id3"


->bindValue(':id1', your_id)
->bindValue(':id2', your_id)
->bindValue(':id3', your_id)

Comment: and if I have 100 ids?

Comment: I ended up construgint the query string in a loop

Comment: you can do that, using a variable

Comment: Use Batch Insert

Comment: If you have that many IDs, I'd consider using another format for providing your where. I prefer "operator syntax" or, array syntax. Get an array of the IDs, then build your update like this: `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('table', ['column' => 'value'], ['in', 'id', $idArray])->execute()`. You can read more here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#where

Answer (score 12):

Try like this,

```
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
        ->update('table_name', [SET_Values], 'CONDITION')
        ->execute();
```

For Example,

```
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
             ->update('users', ['status' => 1], 'age > 30')
             ->execute();
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, if you need to use the column itself in the update query, you must use yii\db\Expression.

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->update('user', ['visits' => new \yii\db\Expression('visits + 1')], 'age > 30')
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
         ->update('customer', ['otp' => $otp_rand], ['custid' => 23])
         ->execute();
```

**this is the right syntax and works & tested in yii2 **

Answer (score 1):

> If you have mpre then one condition then use this

```
$this->localdb->createCommand()
    ->update(
        $this->MYTable,
        [
            'name' => $el['new'],
            'data' => $el['data'],
        ],
        [
            'userId' => $this->user,
            'product_id' => $this->productId,
            'name' => $el['old'],
            'created' => $el['date'],
            'category' => $el['cat'],
        ]

    );
```