# Use select where in query in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

---

It returns no title. 
So what can I change in the query?

```
$query = (new Query())->select('title')->from('topics')->where(['id' => [1, 2, 3]]);
return $query->title;
```

Comment: Check the following links. Might be helpful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469689/yii2-update-field-with-query-builder/25580836#25580836

Answer (score 9):

Your query is formed something like -

```
SELECT title FROM topics WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

So you will get array of array. Also you need to execute the query.

Try -

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['title'])->from('topics')->where(['id' => [1, 2, 3]]);
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
$titles = '';
foreach($data as $row) {
    $titles .= $row['title'] . ', ';
}
return rtrim($titles, ', ');
```

You will get the `title` for each record, comma separated.

Comment: If the above answer has worked fine for you then accept the answer so that it is not listed under the 'Unanswered' list anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
$users=[1,2,3];
User::find()->where('id IN('.$users.')');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [
   'attribute' => 'topic_id',
   'format' => 'raw',
   'value' => function($data){
    $query = (new Query())->select(['title'])->from('topics')->where(['id' => [1, 2, 3]]);
      $command = $query->createCommand();
      $data= $command->queryAll();
      foreach($data as $row)
        return  $data['title'];
      }
 ],
```

m put this code but here error generate this.

Undefined index: title

title is available for topics table.

Comment: Say you get all 3 records then you need to display them as comma separated or something like that?

Comment: Updated the answer. It will return comma separated titles but if you need to return in some other format then modify accordingly.