# Yii2 QueryBuilder Update with Join

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have the following raw SQL query:

```
UPDATE `pay_audit`
JOIN `invoice_items`
ON `invoice_items`.`mdn` = `pay_audit`.`account_id` 
AND `invoice_items`.`unitprice` = `pay_audit`.`payment`
AND `invoice_items`.`producttype_name` LIKE 'PAYMENT'
AND DATE_FORMAT(`invoice_items`.`created`, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-02-21'
SET `pay_audit`.`invoice_item_id` = `invoice_items`.`id`
WHERE `pay_audit`.`report_date` = '2015-02-21'
```

The date is a variable $date in php.

How can i "convert" this raw SQL query into Yii2 QueryBuilder?

[UPDATE]

As Felipe mentioned it's not possible with query builder so i ended up doing it like followed:

```
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "";
    $sql .= "UPDATE `pay_audit` ";
    $sql .= "JOIN `invoice_items` ";
    $sql .= "ON `invoice_items`.`mdn` = `pay_audit`.`account_id` ";
    $sql .= "AND `invoice_items`.`unitprice` = `qpay_audit`.`payment` ";
    $sql .= "AND `invoice_items`.`producttype_name` LIKE 'PAYMENT' ";
    $sql .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(`invoice_items`.`created`, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$today' ";
    $sql .= "SET `pay_audit`.`invoice_item_id` = `invoice_items`.`id` ";
    $sql .= "WHERE `pay_audit`.`report_date` = '$today'";

    $command = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
    $command->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid [Yii 2 Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querybuilder.html) is for **select queries** only.

For **update** queries you have at least three options:

- Raw SQL:

  ```
  \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('update user set status = 1 where age > 30')->execute();
  ```
- Raw SQL with placeholders (to prevent SQL injection)

  ```
  \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('update user set status = :status where age > 30')->bindValue(':status','1')->execute();
  ```
- update() method

  ```
  // update user set status = 1 where age > 30
  \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('user', ['status' => 1], 'age > 30')->execute();
  ```

More info here:

- [Yii DAO](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-dao.md)
- [Another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25469689/436721)