# How to Print UpdateAll query in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I tried printing this query using createCommand, but it is giving boolean error.

RtsSellerEmail::updateAll(['last_check_at' => time() ], ['seller_id' => $sellerId, 'is_sent' => 0, 'email_type' => $emailTypes, ['>', 'created', $release_date]]);

Comment: RtsSellerEmail::updateAll(['last_check_at' => time() ], ['and', ['seller_id' => $sellerId, 'is_sent' => 0, 'email_type' => $emailTypes], ['>', 'created', $release_date]]);

Comment: @SumitAnand why are you print this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469689/yii2-update-field-with-query-builder

Comment: If your purpose is just debug, you should find all the performed queries in the [debug toobar](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-using-the-debugger--cms-26910)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to get query for **ModelName::updateAll(...)**

But we can generate **Raw Query** using below pattern

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand();
echo $command->update(RtsSellerEmail::tableName(),$columns ,$condition)->rawSql;
```

we can use **'sql'** or **'getRawSql()'** insted of **'rawSql'** to generate raw query